# Datatable 'stateSave: true,' crashes table, does anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm displaing a table using Datatable JS, Everything works fine, untill I add the stateSave: true argument, Below is my code without the stateSave, this displays the tables correctly shown below:
[image]

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        colReorder: true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                text: '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">content_copy</i>Copy Current Page</a>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                text: '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">list</i>Export Current Page as CSV</a>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                },
                filename: function () {
                    var today = new Date();
                    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                    today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
                    return 'AZ-CustomTransactionReport: ' + today;
                },
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">picture_as_pdf</i>Export Current Page as PDF</a>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                },
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'A2',
                filename: function () {
                    var today = new Date();
                    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                    today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
                    return 'AZ-CustomTransactionReport: ' + today;
                },
            },

            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">print</i>Print Current Page</a>',
                messageBottom: null
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "targets": [{% for i in transactionCheckBoxes %}{% if i.value == False %} {% if forloop.counter0 == 84 %}{% else %}{{forloop.counter0}}{% endif %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}],
                className: 'hidden',
            },

        ],

    });
```

with the above working fine, the below loads a table that is broken and blacked out with the table data overlapping itslef:
[image]

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        colReorder: true,
        stateSave: true, /*ADDED LINE*********/
        "bPaginate": false,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                text: '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">content_copy</i>Copy Current Page</a>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                text: '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">list</i>Export Current Page as CSV</a>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                },
                filename: function () {
                    var today = new Date();
                    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                    today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
                    return 'AZ-CustomTransactionReport: ' + today;
                },
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">picture_as_pdf</i>Export Current Page as PDF</a>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                },
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'A2',
                filename: function () {
                    var today = new Date();
                    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                    today = dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yyyy;
                    return 'AZ-CustomTransactionReport: ' + today;
                },
            },

            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: '<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons left">print</i>Print Current Page</a>',
                messageBottom: null
            }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "targets": [{% for i in transactionCheckBoxes %}{% if i.value == False %} {% if forloop.counter0 == 84 %}{% else %}{{forloop.counter0}}{% endif %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}],
                className: 'hidden',
            },

        ],

    });
```

I'm using the following libraries:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce your problem.  Just to note: (1) I do see errors in the browser console for both versions of your code, where there are extra commas - for example `},` with no `{` following the comma; and also for one `],`. Worth cleaning up, but probably not the cause. (2) What CSS imports are you using?

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting, good note about the extra syntax, i'll clean it up and see if that helps, the css im using : <script src=" //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script> and <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

Comment: also, those extra commas and syntax are  from my Djano template logic, I'm using that to dynamically hide columns in the columdefs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure why, but adding:

```
stateDuration:-1,
```

seems to of done the trick, enabling localstorage fixes this *bug*
if anyon ecan explain why this happens that'd would be great!
Hope this helps anyone having the same issue